# Trouble with a simple query PyODBC

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

I want to query the following:

The attribute Unknown Hrs is Yes if the employee works on at least one project with NULL
hours, and No otherwise.

And I do this by first making a list, theList containing all relevant social security numbers and consequently:

for i in theList:

```
unknown_hours=process_query("SELECT Distinct COUNT(*) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN='%s'" %i)
```

temp.append(unknown_hours)

the trouble is that I get answers like 1L or 0L and I need them to be integers (for an algorithm). Any thoughts?

Regards
Cenderze

Comment: `int_unknown_hours = int(unknown_hours)`?

Comment: Thank you! I always tend to think outside the easy answers for some reason, but this helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1L` is just the long integer representation of the integer value `1`:

```
>> type(1L)
<type 'long'>
>>> long(1)
1L
>>> int(1L)
1
```

Convert in Python:

```
int(unknown_hours)
```

Or in the database layer:

```
SELECT Distinct CAST(COUNT(*) AS UNSIGNED) FROM Works_On WHERE ISNULL(Hours) AND ESSN='%s'
```

Comment: Thank you! This is my first laboration in python so I forgot to mention that I used a list and int() was not possible. However with your answer I knew what to look for and eventually googled up the map function, so thank you! =)

Comment: Consider using a list comprehension for the integer conversion instead of `map()`. Comparison of the two approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).